# Vídeos do youtube não abrem em full screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

Galera teria como por meio de algum javascript fazer com que um vídeo em meu site não abra em full screen em dispositivos iOS?

Pois estou usando o youtube como um player de música e toda vez que alguém acessa em dispositivos iOS ele abre o vídeo em full screen.
Segue meu código com o playsinline.

```
var buildPlayer = function(videoUrl)
{
     playerLoading = true;

     player = new YT.Player(attrs.container, {
         height: '200',
         width: '200',
         videoId: getIdFromUrl(videoUrl),
         playerVars: {
             enablejsapi: 1,
             playsinline: 1,
             html5: 1,
         },
         events: {
             'onReady': onPlayerReady,
             'onStateChange': onStateChange
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: Na ultima versão da api do youtube, você pode setar o parametro `playsinline` para `1`, para saber mais, da uma olhada na documentação: [https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#playsinline](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?csw=1#playsinline)

Comment: Pode colocar um exemplo reproduzivel? Quero testar mas não tenho um exemplo completo.

Comment: Pode Acho que no iOS só abre em fullscreen mesmo, afinal de contas roda com o "player nativo". Pode ser um BUG do youtube, porque na documentação da apple https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iAdJSProgGuide/PlayingVideosinAds/PlayingVideosinAds.html fala que funciona para "ads".